# jsTree - what jQuery selectors to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jstree

I'm using jsTree.

1) I want to make the root and all it's children dropbale (jQuery UI)

What selector should I use?

2) each child looks like:

```
<a href="#" class=""><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>Default</a>
```

what selector will choose all the anchors whose first child is `<ins class="jstree-icon">` ?

I tried: `$("a>ins")`
but it brought all the children themselves and not the parents anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a:has(ins)')
```

This will find all a tags that contain an ins tag.